# mariadb FROM_UNIXTIME future times limitation

Tags: mariadb

A note for anyone else hitting the same problem. In MariaDB the FROM_UNIXTIME function has a limit to how far into the future it will allow.  DateTime fields and the DATE_ADD functions don't have this limit.

```
MariaDB> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(2155507200) ;
+---------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(2155507200) |
+---------------------------+
| NULL                      |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB> SELECT DATE_ADD("1970-01-01 00:00:00", INTERVAL 2155507200 SECOND) ;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD("1970-01-01 00:00:00", INTERVAL 2155507200 SECOND) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2038-04-22 00:00:00                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

`TIMESTAMP` runs out in 2038, by which time all the computers and software you are using will be recycled and replaced.  If you doubt it, think about what computer stuff you still have from 18 (= 2038-2020) years ago.  Zip.  Nada.

`DATETIME` lasts until `9999-99-99`, a long time from now.

Comment: I still have a Compaq computer from 18 years ago ... it's very robust even if a bit slow (and 32 bit).  Runs Linux OK and satisfactorily acts as a firewall.

Comment: You are pretending to a government agency?

Comment: I expect both MySQL and MariaDB to address the issue in a few years.  I don't know what approach they will take.  Plan A: play with sign bit.  Plan B:  add another byte(s) to the datatype.  Plan C:  Invent a new datatype.  Each would cause some angst among users.